# What is the best practice for creating the packages in android project

Tags: android

I am little bit confused on this point.
On which basis should we create the packages means based on functionalities or based on the type of class.

Please tell me the best practice followed in Android to design the package structure.

Comment: I just noticed that none of your questions have been marked "answered". Its discouraging answering someone who does not mark the "answer". Most of your questions had good detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

For my recent case, I have kept activity's and services together. My async tasks together, and then a support package to keep globals, sharedpreferences adapters and other helper classes. This makes it easy for me to focus and run basic junits on all packages other than the UI package (activity and service one).

When I see my test project and dev project, its easy to know if I have missed out on any class test, since I just compare the packages and its contents. Maintaining consistency between the projects is the key.